# Can we include a class or mathematical representation of a class coded in Python on a research paper/case study in field of energy

Tags: publications, data, science, case-study

I'm writing a paper based on energy optimisation by creating discharge profile based on demand. So i wrote an algo which (not the most efficient) but works great. The problem is the algorithm is based on a class based function and has variables which needs to be updated and one of which is used as the output.

Am i supposed to show the mathematical representation of the algorithm? and if i can, how am i supposed to show loops and iterations? sorry but this is my first paper.

Comment: Use pseodocode I guess would fit your problem. Pseodocode is not language dependent.

Comment: What a journal will publish is up to them. Ask them if you have a target.

Comment: @buffy we are aiming for ICAIES

Comment: @user8469759 Okay, and just for the info, the class contains some functions which keep operating until the target is achieved

Comment: Check their author information and some of the papers they publish. If in doubt ask an editor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comment about pseudocode was correct.

[Here's one example of how to pseudocode an iterative algorithm without going into a lot of implementation details](https://arxiv.org/abs/1802.03426).

[Here's another example from a well known iterative algorithm](https://www.jmlr.org/papers/v9/vandermaaten08a.html)

I've seen other styles that are just as good - whatever you're comfortable writing that someone who's never seen your algorithm can understand is fine.

Comment: I went looking for an actual pseudocode style guide and couldn't find one. So if anyone knows of one, I'd like to have it.

Comment: I doubt that this is exactly what you want, but Edsger Dijkstra invented a simple programming language that was, in effect, a pseudocode sufficient for expressing algorithms. His papers were written with that "language". David Gries, adopted it as well. His book _The Science of Programming_ uses it throughout.

Comment: I asked the editor, took a close look at my class functions and turns out Pseudo code is correct! tbh I should have thought about this earlier and wasted days forming equations out of the operations Im performing, so Thanks all @Buffy @Libor!